# Bigquery output distinct zip rows with json array object for rest of data

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I'm trying to build a bigquery query to have unique zip codes per row.
Rest of data to be in a json object as:

1. an array object
2. without duplicating the state
3. multiple cities for a state are grouped with the state it belongs to in same object
4. multiple state/city combo are separate objects in the array

I've tried many ways but cannot get anywhere close to getting the output.

Sample table

```
zip     state     city
100     NY        city1
100     NY        city2
101     NY        city3
101     NJ        city4
101     NJ        city5
...     ...       ...
```

Output

```
zip     zip_data
100     {"set":[{"state":["NY"],"city":["city1","city2"]}]}
101     {"set":[{"state":["NY"],"city":["city3"]},{"state":["NJ"],"city":["city4","city5"]}]}
...
```

Comment: BigTable or BigQuery?  Those are very different systems.

Comment: Bigquery. Was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT zip, TO_JSON_STRING(STRUCT(`set`)) zip_data
FROM (
  SELECT zip, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(state, city)) `set`
  FROM (
    SELECT zip, state, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT city) city
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
    GROUP BY zip, state
  )
  GROUP BY zip
)
```

If to apply above to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 100 zip, 'NY' state, 'city1' city UNION ALL
  SELECT 100, 'NY', 'city2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 101, 'NY', 'city3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 101, 'NJ', 'city4' UNION ALL
  SELECT 101, 'NJ', 'city5' 
)
SELECT zip, TO_JSON_STRING(STRUCT(`set`)) zip_data
FROM (
  SELECT zip, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(state, city)) `set`
  FROM (
    SELECT zip, state, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT city) city
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
    GROUP BY zip, state
  )
  GROUP BY zip
)
```

output will be

```
Row zip zip_data     
1   100 {"set":[{"state":"NY","city":["city1","city2"]}]}    
2   101 {"set":[{"state":"NY","city":["city3"]},{"state":"NJ","city":["city4","city5"]}]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfect. Spent few days beating my head on this but couldn't figure out the right query. Appreciate it.

Comment: sure. we are here to help!